# Multi-dimensional 0-1 Knapsack problem with a high number of dimensions

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms

I would like to solve a multi-dimensional 0-1 Knapsack problem, by looking for approximation algorithms with constant approximation ratio if possible. Here the particularity is that the number of dimensions $m$ may be as high as the input size. Hence existing approximation algorithms cannot be applied. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Multi-dimensional Knapsack with high number of dimensions are also called Packing Integer Programs (PIPs) and they capture Maximum Independent Set in graphs as a special case so it is very hard to approximate. Here is an old paper of mine on this topic - hardness results have been improved since then but you can look them up. http://chekuri.cs.illinois.edu/papers/vector-sicomp.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion. I will look into them.